# Xamarin.Forms PDF.js not displaying on a physical device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, pdf.js

I'm working on an Android app that generates and displays PDFs.
Currently, I have already generated the PDF all okay, but when I try to view the PDF, (I am using the PDF.js, for offline viewing), on my physical tablet, does not work, just shows me a blank screen. It does not even render the index.html of the PDF.js.
[image: screen shot]

I don't know what's happening.
My code basically follows this tutorial: https://medium.com/medialesson/show-pdf-files-in-your-xamarin-android-app-3718148de1c0 (part of the PDF.js)

I'm guessing the PdfJsWebViewRenderer class. On the devices that work, the OnElementPropertyChanged function is triggered ~3 times with changes in the source, and on the device that doesn't work, the function is never triggered with the "source" property.
I'm setting the source with:

PdfJsWebView.Uri = filePath;

On the constructor of that xaml.cs page. The filePath is for example "/data/user/0/com.Iberdrola.SFIB2Dev/cache/tmp56e9df28.tmp.pdf".

Feel free to ask anything.

Thanks, David